# WP Slideshow Gallery Plugin not loading in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8, slideshow

I am using a Slideshow Gallery plugin on a WordPress site and it is failing to load in IE8. It loads in all other browsers, including IE7 & IE9.

The page is: http://taylorforiowa.com/

The plugin I'm using is WP Slideshow Gallery: http://wpgallery.tribulant.net/

I'm also curious as to the best way to troubleshoot Javascript related errors.

The status bar errors shown are:

```
    User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
    Timestamp: Fri, 29 Jul 2011 17:12:42 UTC


    Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
    Line: 4821
    Char: 5
    Code: 0
    URI: http://robtaylor.frmboy.com/wp-includes/js/prototype.js?ver=1.6.1


    Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
    Line: 196
    Char: 2
    Code: 0
    URI: http://taylorforiowa.com/


    Message: 'expr.:' is null or not an object
    Line: 10
    Char: 247
    Code: 0
    URI: http://robtaylor.frmboy.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-cycle/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=3.1.3


    Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
    Line: 25
    Char: 264
    Code: 0
    URI: http://robtaylor.frmboy.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.4
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It's just broken. If you look in the comments it's been promised that it will be fixed ASAP. Here's a link to the comment, the response is shortly below: http://wpgallery.tribulant.net/blog/2009/12/16/v1-0-3/#comment-266

Comment: I realise that, but do the versions match up?